# Spring integration always mark received messages as read

Tags: java, gmail, spring-integration, imap

I'm receiving incoming messages to my gmail account using Spring integration mail. Messages are received without a problem, but it is always marked in my gmail account as read. Here is my XML configuration:

```
<int:channel id="receiveChannel"/>
replace 'userid and 'password' with the real values
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
                                    store-uri="imaps://proximahaiz%40gmail.com:myPassword@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
                                    channel="receiveChannel"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    should-delete-messages="false"
                                    should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
                                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
/>


<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</
```

I added a parameter **should-mark-messages-as-read = "false"** but all receiving messages still marked as  Read.
I use 4.2.9.RELEASE version of Spring Integration.
This is my java code:

```
public class GmailInboundImapIdleAdapterServiceImpl implements GmailInboundImapIdleAdapterService {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GmailInboundImapIdleAdapterServiceImpl.class);
private static String MAIL_SUBJECT = "mail_subject";
private static String MAIL_FROM = "mail_from";
private static EmailParser emailParser = new EmailParser();
@Autowired
private EmailReceiverService emailReceiverService;


@Override
public void startReceiveEmails() {
    ApplicationContext acProxy = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/integration/gmail-imap-idle-config-proxytest.xml");
    DirectChannel inputChannelProxy = acProxy.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);

    inputChannelProxy.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            initMessageReceiving(message);
        }
    });
}
```

What shall I do to leave messages marked as unread in the gmail account after I received them into my application?

[logs from debug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5W3jCxXRa-PU2Yxc09HTEhXVnM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Change `mail.debug` java property to `true`.

With the should mark messages read flag set to false, the adapter should not set the `\Seen` flag which can be confirmed by looking at the debug output.

If that's the case, Gmail might not be honoring the IMAP protocol and using some other criteria to mark the message as read.

Comment: And it needs to be using FETCH.PEEK, not FETCH, or EXAMINE, and not SELECT.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Uploaded logs, can not you see them and say, what's wrong?

Comment: You need to show more of the log; that only shows the search. Can't you upload the whole thing as a text file?